# JWT in Cookies - do I need a refresh token?

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security, jwt, refresh-token

I'm implementing security for my React SPA using Spring Security on the backend. After a lot of reading, I opted for the following approach :

- HTTPS everywhere
- POST /login takes credentials returns JWT_TOKEN & XSRF_TOKEN in cookie form. I build the JWT_TOKEN myself whereas Spring Security handles the XSRF_TOKEN. Both cookies are Secured and SameSite=Strict. The JWT token is HttpOnly.
- Subsequent API calls require the X-XSRF-TOKEN header. This is read from the aforementionned cookie. Both are sent and Spring Security compares them. JWT is automatically sent and checked in a Filter.
- Every time a XSRF token is used, Spring Security generates a new one to prevent session-fixation attacks
- XSS protections are applied by Spring Security

So now I'm wondering about refresh tokens. I'm reading a lot of contradictory info out there. Do I need them with this setup? If so how best to handle this ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, as its name says, the refresh token changes from one token to another. Typically they are used in OAuth protocol-based authentication. They are useful when an access token has expired, but the user's session is still valid.

First, JWTs are a great choice for access tokens. They have claims that match the access tokens requirements, such as: `exp`, `iat`, `jti`, `sub`, etc. But, when using a cookie-based authentication there is no need for access tokens and possibly no need for JWT.

As you said, your `JWT_TOKEN` is being set as an `HttpOnly` cookie, which means that only the server has access to it. JWT is useful for sharing the initial state between the client and server, and vice-versa. If your server is just taking it to look up the database, you don't need a JWT, you are just using a session concept, and keeping session data on a JWT may not be a good practice.

Second, if your authenticated cookie data will live at `/login` and die at `/logout`, there is no need for refresh tokens. Refresh tokens are an exchange key for short-life access tokens. Instead, your cookies keep the session live and don't need to be exchanged by something else.

For example, if the user uses the `/login` route to exchange your `username` and `password` for one short life `access_token`. He may need the `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token` without needing to send his `username` and `password` again.

If you are using the OAuth protocol or similar, refresh tokens are essential to provide a more seamless experience for your users and avoid the inconvenience of repeatedly having to re-enter their credentials. But even on OAuth, they are not mandatory.

Comment: My understanding is that by storing jwt tokens in cookies (rather than sending them in the response header/body and making calls with an "Authorization" header) one reduces their susceptibility to attacks whilst keeping things stateless (and conforming to OWASP recommendations)

Comment: You are right, but when using cookies you are not keeping things stateless... Cookies are not stateless, they maintain state for a user across multiple requests. So, you are handling two different models: token-based authentication and cookie-based authentication. When using cookie-based authentication, access tokens are not useful because only the server will handle and use this data. JWT however can be used, for example, to keep e-commerce cart data on cookies. You must understand if you want to use token-based or cookie-based authentication.